# XPATH in mule flow returns multiple values

Tags: mule, mule-el

I have a requirement where I run xPath evaluator against xml payload in mule flow. This xPath evaluator can return single or multiple values. I need to store these values in flow variable and use somewhere later in the flow. Can someone help me implementing this changes?

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For extracting values from an XML document, use the XPath extractor.

```
<mulexml:xpath-extractor-transformer expression="/a:my/b:xpath/text()"/>
```

You can also [use](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/dynamic_xpath_values_in_evaluator_using_mel) [Mule Expression Language](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL) to create dynamic XPath expressions:

```
<expression-transformer mimeType="text/xml" evaluator="xpath" expression="//school/day[@date= #[function:datestamp:yyyy-MM-dd] ]/name
"/>
```

However this can get somewhat messy for complicated expressions, so I have created my own [dynamic XPath transformer](https://github.com/skjolber/mule-module-dxpath):

```
<dx:dxpath expression="/b:team[name = $teamName]/b:player[b:name = $playerName]/b:goals/text()">
  <dx:variable key="playerName" value="#[header:invocation:playerName]"/>
  <dx:variable key="teamName" value="#[header:invocation:teamName]"/>
  <!-- unlimited number of variables -->
</dx:dxpath>
```

which is somewhat more easy on the eyes.

Then Wrap your flow with an ericher:

```
<enricher target="#[variable:myData]">
    <processor-chain>
        <!-- your flow here -->
    </processor-chain>
</enricher>
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for responding on this. You know I am able to extract the value from XML using XPATH in mule flow. However my XPATH expression return the array of values. I am not able to get its values using ".text" function at the end of XPATH expression. I am using below expression: <set-variable variableName="changeElements" value="#[xpath(&quot;//Life/LifeRequest/ChangeSubType[LifEExtension/ChangeSubTypeExtension/ChangeObjectType/@tc='6']/ElementName&quot;)]" />. My exact requirement is to pass this array of values to XSLT and use it there.